# Cancel adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I'm kinda new to android and I wonder is it possible if after I've run notifyDataSetChanged(), I can cancel it in the middle.

For eg my case :

I would getPrice() then getTransaction if onResponse gets 1 as response.

I would set a swipeRefreshListener with the current code :

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onRefresh() {
                                getTransactions(view);

                                Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                                fadeIn.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
                                fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                layoutBalance.setAnimation(fadeIn);
                                mActivities_RecyclerView.setAnimation(fadeIn);
                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

mActivities_RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        });
```

I will recall getTransaction as I will need to get most updated data from the API. 
But because my API call using retrofit enqueue will run async, my data would refresh first before I get the actual data from the server.

So, my question is that can I cancel `notifyDataSetChanged()` or do I need to change my implementation?

Comment: add a condition to check if the contents of your existing datamodel is equal to the new model,if its equal you don't need to do notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @Venky the call api thing is enqueue so even I set boolean. It would just run first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've a Datamodel called as `"APIData"` and now you have once assigned it to the adapter and recyclerview,after the Swipereferesh happens and you have received the refreshed data,which would again be in a datamodel called as `"APIData"`,now lets assume this to be `APIData2`,now just use

```
APIData.equals(APIData2)
```

this would check if the previous data is same to the new one,if its true you dont need to do `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: sorry, my bad it would be the fadein thing that I need to handle. I just happens to debug it now.

Comment: And just a small suggestion to use setRefreshing(false) after notifyDataSetChanged